# Not able to validate credit card using active merchant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credit-card, activemerchant

When i charge credit card using form, it throws validation error "The credit card information you provided is not valid. Please double check the information you provided and then try again."

Any solution??

This is my payment.rb

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  require "active_merchant/billing/rails"

  attr_accessor :card_security_code
  attr_accessor :credit_card_number
  attr_accessor :expiration_month
  attr_accessor :expiration_year

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :card_security_code, presence: true
  validates :credit_card_number, presence: true
  validates :expiration_month, presence: true, numericality: {          greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 12 }
  validates :expiration_year, presence: true
  validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }

  validate :valid_card

  def credit_card
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        number:              credit_card_number,
        verification_value:  card_security_code,
        month:               expiration_month,
        year:                expiration_year,
        first_name:          first_name,
        last_name:           last_name
 )
  end

  def valid_card
     if !credit_card.valid?
      errors.add(:base, "The credit card information you provided is not valid.  Please double check the information you provided and then try again.")
     false
    else
     true
    end
  end

  def process
    if valid_card
      response = GATEWAY.authorize(amount * 100, credit_card)
      if response.success?
        transaction = GATEWAY.capture(amount * 100, response.authorization)
        if !transaction.success?
          errors.add(:base, "The credit card you provided was declined.  Please double check your information and try again.") and return
          false
        end
        update_columns({authorization_code: transaction.authorization, success: true})
        true
      else
        errors.add(:base, "The credit card you provided was declined.  Please double check your information and try again.") and return
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is my activemerchant.rb

```
if Rails.env == 'development'
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::FirstdataE4Gateway.wiredump_device =   File.open(Rails.root.join('log','active_merchant.log'), 'a+')
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::FirstdataE4Gateway.wiredump_device.sync = true
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

  login = 'mylogin'
  password='mypassword'
elsif Rails.env == 'production'
  login = 'mylogin'
  password='mypassword'
end
GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::FirstdataE4Gateway.new({
                                                          login: login,
                                                          password: password
                                                      })
```

Check [here](https://richonrails.com/articles/credit-card-processing-with-active-merchant)

Comment: just as suggestion for refactoring your process `method` http://pastebin.com/7qEkNUau

Answer (score 0):

You also need to provide credit card brand name as

```
def credit_card
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        number:              credit_card_number, # 4111111111111111
        verification_value:  card_security_code, # 123
        month:               expiration_month, # 1
        year:                expiration_year, # 2020
        first_name:          first_name, # Bibek
        last_name:           last_name, # Sharma
        brand:               credit_card_brand # visa
     )
  end
```

Comment: You can also find here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/ActiveMerchant/Billing/CreditCard

Comment: Can you try `type` instead of `brand`?

Comment: Are you using test account?Can you post all the values ?

Comment: Can you post  values as well

Comment: posted and added a link as well @bipashant

Comment: @NitinRajan Can you please try test values I've added on code